# Custom Cycle Time

Tags: rally

How do I determine how long something spent in a state? Here is a query I have for pulling specifics on a user story, but I'm trying to understand how to get the duration something spent in In Progress before going to completed. To be more specific, customizing Cycle Time

https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/xxxx/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"FormattedID":"US41","_PreviousValues.ScheduleState":"In-Progress"}&fields=["ScheduleState","_ValidFrom","_ValidTo","_PreviousValues"]&hydrate=["ScheduleState","_ValidFrom","_ValidTo","_PreviousValues"]&sort={_ValidFrom: -1}&pagesize=1

I don't see where the ValidFrom and ValidTo provides that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems to be working for me. Hope it helps!

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
            fetch   : ['ScheduleState'],
            hydrate : ['ScheduleState'],
            filters : [{
                property : '_UnformattedID',
                value    : 41
            }],
            sorters : [{
                property  : '_ValidTo',
                direction : 'ASC'
            }]
        }).load({
            params : {
                compress                    : true,
                removeUnauthorizedSnapshots : true
            },
            callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                var cycleTime = Rally.util.DateTime.getDifference(new Date(Rally.util.Array.last(Ext.Array.filter(records, function(record) {
                    return record.get('ScheduleState') === 'Accepted';
                })).get('_ValidFrom')), new Date(Rally.util.Array.last(Ext.Array.filter(records, function(record) {
                    return record.get('ScheduleState') === 'In-Progress';
                })).get('_ValidFrom')), 'day'));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: Using the LBAPI, it would be better to provide an ObjectID vs an _UnformattedID since you could also mistakenly receive defects, test cases, or other work items in the results.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code Conner.  I need a slight tweak to that though as I'm trying to get the date that an item moves into Completed or my custom KanbanState.  I'm not finding any documentation on what the field name of the timestamp when a move occurs is.  Should I be using the ETLDate? Or something else.

Comment: The function I gave for getting the difference between the two dates should provide the dates you need. "new Date(Rally.util.Array.last(Ext.Array.filter(records, function(record) { return record.get('ScheduleState') === 'Accepted'; })).get('_ValidFrom'))" is the date that the work item last went into the "Accepted" state. There's also a field which would allow you to pull this info directly, "AcceptedDate", however this method will work better if you are trying to use a custom schedule state.

Comment: Thanks Conner.  This gave me the perfect starting point to pick out what I needed.