# Rally custom Cycle/Lead Time data via Lookback API

Tags: rally, appsdk2, lookbackapi

I am trying to generate custom (and highly granular) cycle/lead time data for tabular and chart views using the REST API from JavaScript.

I have a custom (non-required) field on my stories & defects, c_KanbanStatus with the following possible values [ null, "Kickoff", "PO", "Creative", "Team Backlog", "Coding", "Acceptance Testing", "Accepted" ].

I only recently added this custom field, so a lot of my stories don't have that field (or weren't 'born' with it).

My thinking goes as follows:

- Do a Lookback query for each kanban status transition
- Aggregate by ObjectID
- For each ObjectID, for each state, calculate the time-delta between when the object enters that state and when the object enters the subsequent state.

This is an extract of my code:

```
    var kanbanStates =
    [
        "Kickoff",
        "PO",
        "Creative",
        "Team Backlog",
        "Coding",
        "Acceptance Testing"
    ];

    var username = "**************";
    var password = "**************";

    var deferreds = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < kanbanStates.length; i++)
    {
        var find =
        {
            _ProjectHierarchy: ***************,
            "_PreviousValues.c_KanbanStatus": { $lt: kanbanStates[i] },
            c_KanbanStatus: kanbanStates[i]
        };

        var config =
        {
            url:"https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/********/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find=" + JSON.stringify(find) + "&fields=true&pagesize=999999",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
            }
        };

        deferreds.push($.ajax(config));
    }

    var aggregateResultsByObjectID = function(results)
    {
        var resultsByItemID = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            if(!results[i][0].Results.c_KanbanStatus === kanbanStates[i])
                throw "States don't match!";

            for(var j = 0; j < results[i][0].Results.length; j++)
            {
                var itemID = results[i][0].Results[j].ObjectID;

                if(!resultsByItemID.hasOwnProperty(itemID))
                {
                    resultsByItemID[itemID] =
                    {
                        creationDate: results[i][0].Results[j].CreationDate,
                        name: results[i][0].Results[j].Name,
                        states: [],
                        results: []
                    };
                } 

                resultsByItemID[itemID].results.push(results[i][0].Results[j]);
                resultsByItemID[itemID].states.push(results[i][0].Results[j].c_KanbanStatus);
            }
        }
        return resultsByItemID;
    };

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function()
    {
        var resultsByItemID = aggregateResultsByObjectID(arguments);
        console.log(resultsByItemID);
    });
```

The problem with this query is that I get multiple results back for each ObjectID for each state, even though I specify I only want those snapshots that have differing c_KanbanStatus fields. When I check the results, for the same ObjectID and the same combination if c_KanbanStatus and _PreviousValues.c_KanbanStatus, I get a lot of snapshots back, each with some other field edit.

For example, for the same ObjectID, I get these two results:

```
_PreviousValues:
{
    _User: 10301773174
    c_KanbanStatus: null
},
c_KanbanStatus: "Coding"
```

AND

```
_PreviousValues:
{
    ScheduleState: 10148772688
    _User: 10148977759
},
c_KanbanStatus: "Coding"
```

I expect the first result (snapshot for when it went from not having a c_KanbanStatus field set, to "Coding"). The second result seems to imply it went from not having a c_KanbanStatus field at all, to "Coding", but why?

I have a feeling I'm missing something deep in the Lookback API. Please help me understand!

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971688/custom-cycle-time . Records that meet a condition are returned `Ext.Array.filter(records, function(record) {  
                    return record.get('ScheduleState') === 'Accepted'` and filtered further using `Rally.util.Array.last`

Answer (score 1):

It is expected to get multiple results back for each state. A snapshot is created every time a story is modified. Let's say there are four c_Kanban states: `backlog`, `in-progress`, `done` and `released`. To continue with this example, I move a story to in-progress column and set story's PlanEstimate, then block the task under that story, unblock the task, set task's State to Completed, and finally move the story to  the done column on the Kanban board. All these changes will have unique snapshots created while `c_Kanban === 'in-progress'`

I have an app in this [github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/caclulate-cycle-time-kanban) that builds a grid with columns for times a story spent in each c_Kanban state. Notice `Blocked: true` in one snapshot and `Blocked: false` in another while `c_Kanban: "in-progress"`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, much appreciated! However, you missed part of my explanation, I believe. I understand what you are showing, and your example is expected to return multiple snapshots because you are only querying against c_Kanban === "in-progress", therefore any change (blocked, name, description, etc) made while the item is still in "in-progress" will trigger such a snapshot. However, in my specific case I was querying on the _PreviousValue object as well, and that should only ever return one item (the transition from "in-progress" to "testing" can only happen ONCE).

Comment: Try adding this filter: `{
                    property : '_PreviousValues.c_Kanban',
                    operator    : 'exists',
                    value: true
                }` I  get only one snapshot per state when I add this filter to my filters array.

Comment: Thanks! I'm experimenting with a different approach but will try using that filter as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around with my own solution to this problem, this is what I have come up with. It requires some more tuning to handle the corner cases, but it's close to what I need. I will continue development and create a GitHub repo for this in case anyone could use this.

EDIT: GitHub repo: https://github.com/bfanti/RallyCustomCycleTimeApp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>

    <!--App information-->
    <meta name="Name" content="App: Custom Cycle Time Table"/>
    <meta name="Version" content="1.0"/>
    <meta name="Vendor" content=""/>

    <!--Include SDK-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>

    <!--App code-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var kanbanStatuses =
        [
            "New Feature",
            "Kickoff",
            "PO",
            "Creative",
            "Team Backlog",
            "Coding",
            "Acceptance Testing"
        ];

        var shirtSizeLUT =
        {
            3: "S",
            5: "M",
            8: "L"
        };

        Rally.onReady(function()
        {
            Ext.define("CustomApp",
            {
                extend: "Rally.app.App",
                componentCls: "app",

                launch: function()
                {
                    var self = this;

                    Ext.create("Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore",
                    {
                        fetch   : [ "_UnformattedID", "_TypeHierarchy", "Name", "PlanEstimate", "c_KanbanStatus", "ScheduleState" ],
                        hydrate : [ "c_KanbanStatus", "ScheduleState" ],
                        filters :
                        [
                            {
                                property : "_ProjectHierarchy",
                                value    : ***********
                            },
                            {
                                property: "_TypeHierarchy",
                                value: { $nin: [ -51009, -51012, -51031, -51078 ] }
                            },
                            {
                                property: "_ValidFrom",
                                value: { $gt: "2013-09-13" }
                            }
                        ],
                        sorters :
                        [
                            {
                                property  : "_ValidTo",
                                direction : "ASC"
                            }
                        ]
                    }).load(
                    {
                        params:
                        {
                            compress: false,
                            removeUnauthorizedSnapshots: true
                        },
                        callback : function(records, operation, success)
                        {
                            var aggregateCycleTimes = [];

                            var allObjectIDs = {};
                            Ext.Array.each(records, function(record) { allObjectIDs[record.get("ObjectID")] = record.get("ObjectID"); });

                            for(var storyIndex = 0; storyIndex < Object.keys(allObjectIDs).length; storyIndex++)
                            {
                                (function()
                                {
                                    var currentObjectID = parseInt(Object.keys(allObjectIDs)[storyIndex], 10);
                                    var recordsByStory = Ext.Array.filter(records, function(record) { return record.get("ObjectID") === currentObjectID; });

                                    var currentStateOfStory = "";
                                    var currentStateOfStorySnapshot = Ext.Array.filter(recordsByStory, function(record) { return record.get("_ValidTo").indexOf("9999") !== -1; })[0];
                                    if(currentStateOfStorySnapshot)
                                        currentStateOfStory = currentStateOfStorySnapshot.get("c_KanbanStatus");

                                    var formattedID = (Ext.Array.contains(recordsByStory[0].get("_TypeHierarchy"), -51006) ? "DE" : "US") + recordsByStory[0].get("_UnformattedID");
                                    var cycleTimes =
                                    {
                                        id: formattedID,
                                        name: recordsByStory[0].get("Name"),
                                        planEstimate: shirtSizeLUT[Rally.util.Array.last(recordsByStory).get("PlanEstimate")],
                                        currentStateOfStory: currentStateOfStory
                                    };

                                    var allStatusesAreNull = true;

                                    for(var i = 0; i < kanbanStatuses.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        var currentStatus = kanbanStatuses[i];

                                        var currentSnapshot = Ext.Array.filter(recordsByStory, function(record) { return record.get("c_KanbanStatus") === currentStatus; })[0];

                                        if(!currentSnapshot)
                                        {
                                            cycleTimes[currentStatus] = null;
                                            continue;
                                        }

                                        var firstDate = new Date(currentSnapshot.get("_ValidFrom"));

                                        var nextSnapshot = Rally.util.Array.last(Ext.Array.filter(recordsByStory, function(record) { return record.get("c_KanbanStatus") === currentStatus; }));
                                        var secondDate = new Date();

                                        if(nextSnapshot && (new Date(nextSnapshot.get("_ValidTo"))).getFullYear() !== 9998)
                                            secondDate = new Date(nextSnapshot.get("_ValidTo"));

                                        var cycleTime = Rally.util.DateTime.getDifference(secondDate, firstDate, "day");
                                        cycleTimes[currentStatus] = cycleTime;

                                        if(cycleTime !== null)
                                            allStatusesAreNull = false;
                                    }

                                    if(!allStatusesAreNull)
                                        aggregateCycleTimes.push(cycleTimes);
                                })();
                            }

                            var myStore = Ext.create("Rally.data.custom.Store",
                            {
                                data: aggregateCycleTimes,
                                pageSize: 100,
                            });

                            var columnConfig = 
                            [
                                {
                                    text: "ID",
                                    dataIndex: "id"
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Name",
                                    dataIndex: "name",
                                    width: "280px"
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Size",
                                    dataIndex: "planEstimate"
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Current State",
                                    dataIndex: "currentStateOfStory"
                                }
                            ];

                            for (var i = 0; i < kanbanStatuses.length; i++)
                            {
                                var columnConfigElement = {}; 
                                columnConfigElement["text"] = kanbanStatuses[i];
                                columnConfigElement["dataIndex"] = kanbanStatuses[i];
                                columnConfig.push(columnConfigElement);
                            }

                            if (!self.grid)
                            {
                                self.grid = self.add(
                                {
                                    xtype: "rallygrid",
                                    itemId: "mygrid",
                                    store: myStore,
                                    columnCfgs: columnConfig
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp("CustomApp", { name: "My Custom App" });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```